# Awkward string passing into shell by nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex, shell, whitespace

I've been using a script lib written by [millermedeiros](https://gist.github.com/millermedeiros/4724047) (*thanks to him*) to execute multiple shell commands synchronously in nodejs.

But interestingly whatever I've tried, I could not pass a string containing white spaces.

So, here is the lib code (`./shellHelper.js`):

```
exports.series = function(cmds, cb){
var execNext = function(){
    exports.exec(cmds.shift(), function(err){
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        } else {
            if (cmds.length) execNext();
            else cb(null);
        }
    });
};
execNext();
};
```

And here is my code (`./gitcommit.js`):

```
var shell = require('./shellHelper');
...
var regex = '/\s([A-Z0-9])\w+/g';
var message = input.replace(regex); //input string is coming from prompt module
...
var command1 = 'git add .';
var command2 = 'git commit -m \"' + message + '\"';
var command3 = 'git push origin master';
...
shell.series([ command1, command2, command3], function(err){
   console.log('executed many commands in a row');
   console.log(command2);
  });
});
```

It does work, unless I type a message with spaces. Console stdout is:

```
$ ..\nodejs (master)
$ node gitcommit.js
Enter commit message :
prompt: name:  something contains white spaces
error: pathspec 'contains' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'white' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'spaces"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
executed many commands in a row
git commit -m "something contains white spaces"
```

Comment: Second argument of `input.replace()` is missing. (replace(something, with something)

Comment: Usually this error occurs when you use quotes instead of doublequotes, for example `git commit -m 'my commit message'` instead of  `git commit -m "my commit message"`. I'm not sure you need to escape your double quotes, did you try without escaping them, i mean `'git commit -m "' + message + '"'` ?

Comment: Yeah there should have been replacing the string for 'command2' by regex. I changed it to "var message = input.replace(' ', result.name.pattern);" . That works now